# List to dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, odk

I have the result of a select_multiple question stored in a list. That comes from a dataset collected with [OpenDataKit](https://opendatakit.org)

```
example <- list("a", c("b", "c"), c("d", "e", "f"), c(""))
```

In the example below for the record `#4`, there were no answers (meaning `NA` for all options).

I need to create a data frame from this list where each options from the select multiple would become a new variable.  Each element of the list is *de facto* not of the same length.

The result should look like this:

```
variable | a   b    c    d     e    f
row1     | 1   0    0    0     0    0
row2     | 0   1    1    0     0    0 
row3     | 0   0    0    1     1    1
row4     | <NA> <NA><NA> <NA><NA> <NA>
```

I have found options with `stri_list2matrix` but that does not provide the expected results.

I tried as well

```
df <-data.frame( lNames <- rep(names(example), lapply(example, length)),
                  lVal <- unlist(example))
```

and got the same

```
arguments imply differing number of rows
```

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `setNames`, `stack` and `dcast` for that:

```
example <- list("a", c("b", "c"), c("d", "e", "f"), c(""))
example <- setNames(example, seq_along(example))

ex2 <- stack(example)
ex2[ex2$values=='','values'] <- NA

library(reshape2)
dcast(ex2, ind ~ values, fun.aggregate = length)
```

This will result in:

```
  ind a b c d e f NA
1   1 1 0 0 0 0 0  0
2   2 0 1 1 0 0 0  0
3   3 0 0 0 1 1 1  0
4   4 0 0 0 0 0 0  1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.

When I run the code, I get an error:

> ex2 <- stack(example, names(example))
Error in if (drop) { : argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (drop) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: Nice!! Can anyone explain why the above answer , which uses setNames, works but directly assigning `ex2 <- stack(example, seq_along(example))` produces message "Error in rep.int(names(x), lengths(x)) : invalid 'times' value"

Comment: @epi99 - because it's superfluous - the names are already on `example` from the previous line and are then used to name the `stack`. It could have just been `stack(example)` and you would get the same result.

Comment: @user3148607 Could you be more specific? It working fine for me